# C Pointers, understanding how to pass arrays to function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, function-call

I'm currently revising on C pointers for an upcoming test and I came across a rather interesting program as I was running through the lecture slides.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr);//function prototype, input is a dereferenced pointer

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "cHaRaCters and $32.98";

    printf("The string before conversion is %s\n", string);
    convertToUppercase(string); //Why can I just input the string array into the function? I don't need a pointer?
    printf("The string after conversion is %s", string);
}

void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr)
{
    while (*sPtr != '\0')//Clearly see the NULL terminating character, means the entire array is passed to the function.
    {
        *sPtr = toupper(*sPtr);
        sPtr++;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is this particular line: **convertToUppercase(*string*);**

The function prototype requires a (char *sPtr) as an input, but for this case, the string array is just passed into the function call. How?

I don't really understand how this works. Can anyone help me to understand this code better?

My guess is that the array name itself 'string' already contain the address of the entire array itself (That's why when we assign pointers to array we don't put the '&')

Thank you in advance, take care!

Comment: In most expressions, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element, so `convertToUppercase(string);` is equivalent to `convertToUppercase(&string[0]);`. The array is said to "decay" to a pointer in these expressions.

Comment: That was what I thought too. 

But why is the entire array passed into the function? If you use 'string' as an input, wouldn't it only pass on the first element into the function?

How is the entire array passed inside?

Comment: Only a pointer to the first element is passed to the function. The array contains a null terminator after the last character of the string, so the function can look for the null terminator.

Comment: I see I see!

This means that the pointer that points to the first element is passed in. However due to the while loop, and condition being NULL, it will continue to pass through the entire array until it reaches the NULL character (condition met?)

This means that the entire array doesn't need to be passed into the function, only the pointer to the first element?

Comment: Yes, now you understand.

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you so much kind sir!

Comment: But the word NULL in capitals usually means a null pointer value rather than a null terminator character. A null terminator character is just a character with numeric code 0. You may also see the null terminator character written (in descriptions) as NUL because that is what the character with numeric code 0 is called In the ASCII standard.

Comment: Rather than putting "solved" in the title, you should [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it addressed your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters having array types are adjusted by the compiler to pointer types to the array element types.

So for example these two function declarations

```
void convertToUppercase(char sPtr[]);
```

and

```
void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr);
```

declare the same one function.

You may include the both declarations in your program though the compiler can issue a message that there are redundant declarations of the same function.

On the other hand, array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions (as for example using in the `sizeof` operator) are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So this function call

```
convertToUppercase(string)
```

is equivalent to the following function call

```
convertToUppercase( &string[0] )
```

Pay attention to that it will be better to declare and define the function the following way

```
char * convertToUppercase( char s[] )
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!

In the program, the entire array is passed into the function. How is that so?

I would think that only the first element gets passed into the function.

Comment: @FermiToh As all elements of an array are stored adjacently then having the pointer to the first element of an array you can access any element of the array using the pointer arithmetic that lies for example under the hood of the subscript operator.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much kind sir! Realy appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays auto-convert to pointers when passed to functions. It just does, as if you a had written `convertToUppercase((char*)string);`. Just one more implicit type conversion rule.